# Typedefs in circular-dependend classes

Tags: c++, class, templates, typedef, circular-dependency

I have a few classes (`A`, `B`, `C`) each with a member with a templated (`Ptr<...>`) type depending on the incomplete type of another class (circular). I'd like to typedef the types (`::ptr`) as shown below. This seems not to work – my compiler tells me the following:

```
In file included from B.hpp:6:0,
                 from A.hpp:6:
C.hpp:13:8: error: ‘ptr’ in ‘class A’ does not name a type
     A::ptr a;
        ^
```

However using `T*` instead of `T::ptr` makes it working. How can I fix that?

A.hpp:

```
#ifndef TEST_INCLUDE_A
#define TEST_INCLUDE_A 1

class A;

#include "B.hpp"

#include "P.hpp"

class A {
public:
    typedef Ptr<A> ptr;
    B::ptr b;
};

#endif
```

B.hpp:

```
#ifndef TEST_INCLUDE_B
#define TEST_INCLUDE_B 1

class B;

#include "C.hpp"

#include "P.hpp"

class B {
public:
    typedef Ptr<B> ptr;
    C::ptr c;
};

#endif
```

C.hpp:

```
#ifndef TEST_INCLUDE_C
#define TEST_INCLUDE_C 1

class C;

#include "A.hpp"

#include "P.hpp"

class C {
public:
    typedef Ptr<C> ptr;
    A::ptr a;
};

#endif
```

P.hpp:

```
#ifndef TEST_INCLUDE_PTR
#define TEST_INCLUDE_PTR 1

template<class T>
class Ptr {
public:
    T* ptr_t;
};

#endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the purpose of resolving the circular dependency, you're just going to have to give the compiler a hand and impart some foreknowledge of what `ptr` is going to be in the other class, that is: you know that `A::ptr` is `Ptr<A>`, and so on.

[online demo](http://ideone.com/J6sqnG)

```
class A;
class B;

template<typename T>
struct Ptr { T* ptr_t; };

class A {
public:
    using ptr = Ptr<A>;
    Ptr<B> b;
};

class B {
public:
    using ptr = Ptr<B>;
    Ptr<A> a;
};

int main() {
    A a;
    B b;
    a.b.ptr_t = &b;
    b.a.ptr_t = &a;

    A::ptr aptr;
    B::ptr bptr;
    aptr.ptr_t = &a;
    bptr.ptr_t = &b;
    a.b = bptr;
    b.a = aptr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are certain operations that you can only do on a complete type. One of them is, from [basic.def.odr]:

> A class type `T` must be complete if:
>   — [...]
>   — a class member access operator is applied to an expression of type `T` (5.2.5), or
>   — [...]

Writing `A::ptr` requires `A` to be complete. `A` is not complete at the point where we're defining `C`, so this is an error.

On the other hand, when you write `A*` however, that does *not* require `A` to be complete. Having pointers (or references) to incomplete types as members is fine.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion:

1. Update the definition of `P` slightly to define a derived typename.

   ```
   template<class T>
   class Ptr {
   public:
       using ptr_t = T*;
       ptr_t ptr;
   };
   ```
2. Update A.hpp, B.hpp and C.hpp to rely only on forward declarations of `B`, `C`, and `A`, respectively.

   The updated version of A.hpp.

   ```
   #ifndef TEST_INCLUDE_A
   #define TEST_INCLUDE_A 1

   #include "P.hpp"

   class B;

   class A {
      public:
         typedef Ptr<A> ptr;   // This does not seem useful any longer
                               // It can probably be removed.
         Ptr<B> b_ptr;
   };

   #endif
   ```

   Update B.hpp and C.hpp similarly.